# Displaying Message

Tags: php, codeigniter

Question is inside of the index function is where I was going to grab the two variables and use them to run a function that checks the values against the database and see if they match a record and if so it validates the activation from the email however I'm trying to figure out what I should do with the message here. What I want to do is display a certain message for a successful activation and a message saying it wasn't a successful activation with the same page loading. How should this be attempted?

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Activate extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('auth');
}

public function index($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons =  '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    $x = 0;
    if(($param1 !== NULL)&&($param2 !== NULL))
    {

        //params not null yay..
        if((isset($param1))&&((trim($param1) !== '')||(!empty($param1))))
        {
            if(!is_numeric($param1))
            {
              $x++;
            }
        }
        if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $param2))
            {
              $x++;
            }
        }


        if($x !== 0)
        {
           $bodyContent = $this->config->item('defaultTemplate') ."error_page";
        }
        else
        {
           $bodyContent = $this->config->item('defaultTemplate') ."/usermanagement/forms/activate";//which view file
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }
    $bodyType = "full";//type of template   

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view($this->config->item('defaultTemplate') .'/usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

}

/* End of file activate.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/activate.php */
```

**EDIT :**

I'm trying to figure out where I need to run my function that gets both parameters and checks them against the database and then if the result returns true then the user validating.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Activate extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('auth');
}

public function index($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons =  '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    $x = 0;
    if(($param1 !== NULL)&&($param2 !== NULL))
    {

        //params not null yay..
        if((isset($param1))&&((trim($param1) !== '')||(!empty($param1))))
        {
            if(!is_numeric($param1))
            {
              $x++;
            }
        }
        if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $param2))
            {
              $x++;
            }
        }


        if($x !== 0)
        {
           $bodyContent = $this->config->item('defaultTemplate') ."error_page";
           $message = 'User was not activated successfully! Please try again with the right credentials!';
        }
        else
        {
           $bodyContent = $this->config->item('defaultTemplate') ."/usermanagement/forms/activate";//which view file
           $message = 'User was activated successfully! You may now login!';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }
    $this->data['message'] = $message;
    $bodyType = "full";//type of template   

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view($this->config->item('defaultTemplate') .'/usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

}

/* End of file activate.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/activate.php */
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use `$this->session->flashdata()`